# Promises inside a setInterval

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, promise, setinterval

I've got a `setInterval` that runs a promise every second, inside the then function of every promise, I put the output into a MongoDB database (although for some reason it's not working).

I want to close the connection to the database when everything is done, but I don't know how to to make the closing of the connection only run when all promises are done and everything has finished writing to the DB.

Here is my current code:

I've got a `client.js` file, meant to issue the query to a shop, using a promise, and a `db.js`, meant to handle DB functionality.

### client.js

```
var id = setInterval(function(){

        if (i == (categories.length-1))
            clearInterval(id);


            var category = categories[i];

            client.itemSearch({  
              searchIndex: SearchIndex,
              categoryID: category.id,
              keywords: currentKeyword
            })
            .then(function(results){

                var title = results[0].Title;
                var cat = category.name;
                var price = results[0].Price

                db.insertProduct(title,cat,price).then(function(){
                    console.log("Added " + title);
                })
            },function(err) {
                console.log("error at " + category.name);
            });
            i+=1;
    }, 1000)

queryStore();
```

### db.js

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/catalog');

var schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title           : String,
    category        : String,
    price           : Number,
}, {collection: "catalog"});

var Product = mongoose.model("Product", schema);

Product.remove({}, function() {
    console.log('Database cleared.') 
});


exports.clearDB = function() {
    Product.remove({});
}

exports.insertProduct = function (Title,Category,Price) {
    var entry = new Product({
        title: Title,
        category: Category,
        price: Price,
    });

    entry.save();
}

exports.closeConn = function() {
    console.log("Closing DB Connection");
    mongoose.connect().close();
}
```

Also, since I'm absolutely new to JavaScript and Node.js in general, any best practices or general tips will be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: Promises are not "run", they only are created.

Comment: I really recommend not to use `setInterval` together with promises. Promisify `setTimeout` and only use that.

Comment: @Bergi could you elaborate? I'm not sure I understand what that means

Comment: If you refer to my first comment, it's just about terminology. Promises are values, not something that can be executed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As written you are relying on a 1 second interval to impose a delay between successive calls of a search/insert sequence. There's nothing fundamentally wrong with that but it doesn't guarantee that each step is complete before the next one starts, and doesn't guarantee that the next step starts as soon as possible. At each step, the 1 second delay may be more than adequate or less than adequate, you don't really know.

Fortunately, promises offer a much better way to cope with the asynchronism.

Starting with an array, a well tried `reduce` pattern is available (see "The Collection Kerfuffle" [here](http://taoofcode.net/promise-anti-patterns/) to impose a sequence :

```
array.reduce(function(promise, item) {
    return promise.then(function() {
        return doSomethingAsync(item);
    });
}, Promise.resolve());
```

where `Promise` is ES6's native Promise, or eg Bluebird.

For the code in the question, the `doSomethingAsync()` part expands to give :

```
categories.reduce(function(promise, category) {
    return promise.then(function() {
        return client.itemSearch({
            'searchIndex': SearchIndex,
            'categoryID': category.id,
            'keywords': currentKeyword
        }).then(function(results) {
            var title = results[0].Title;
            var cat = category.name;
            var price = results[0].Price;
            return db.insertProduct(title, cat, price);
        }).then(function() {
            console.log("Added " + title);
        }).catch(function(err) {
            console.log("error at " + category.name);
        });
    });
}, Promise.resolve());
```

The entire reduction process returns a promise, which can itself be returned and/or aggregated with other promises.

Comment: I have modified your code slightly, hope you don't mind :)

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot! that article you linked was superb. But ive got a question, why in the reduce function do you give Promise.Resolve() as an initial value? and also, why do you wrap the itemsearch function in a promise, why not just use then() on the item search function?

Comment: The reduction process needs a "starter promise" so that the variable `promise` is "thenable" in the first iteration. The starter promise needs to be resolved (at some point) to ensure that the promise chain built by the reduction process starts to settle. Whereas it is typical, in this pattern, for the starter promise to be ready-resolved (as above), it could be a promise that becomes resolved later, in response to some asynchronism.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 thanks a lot! this was perfect. On an unrelated note, how do i make the entire function queryStore() a promise? so that when it is finished completely i could then() it?

Comment: [Promise.resolve(value)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve) returns a promise that is resolved with the given value. Therefore, `Promise.resolve(queryStore())` will return a promise resolved with whatever `queryStore()` returns. If `queryStore()` happened already to return a promise, no worries - `Promise.resolve()` is smart enough to know not to "double-wrap" the returned value.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 it finally clicked. How promises work, thanks a lot! adding `return catagories.reduce(function(promise, category) {` did the trick, and adding return to the database save function made it so it wont close before everything has been entered to the db. Once again, thanks for all the help!

Comment: @CakeToppings, once promises have clicked, you have them for life. May they bring you much luck and good fortune.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 Please be aware that the documentation link will be non-functional in the near future, which is why I made the edit removing it.

Comment: @JoelGritter, yes I'm aware and was hoping that a [Community](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) bot might, at some point, sort out these legacy links. Is there now an instruction to remove them?

Comment: @Roamer-1888 Yes, there is a meta topic that asks for the help of SO users to remove these links: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356294/removing-documentation-reputation-archive-and-links That's what I was doing when I edited your answer.

Comment: @JoelGritter, ah right, thanks for that. I think I would prefer that particular link to be handled under the second bullet point "If Documentation content helps answer the question, ...". Leave it with me and I'll make a decision.